# graph the surface and compute the area

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I need to graph the surface z = (1+x^2)/(1+y^2) above the square region |x|+|y|<= 1. Then I must find its area.

So far to graph ive tried this

`region2 =  ImplicitRegion[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1, z = (1 + x^2)/(1 + y^2)}, {x, y, z}]`
`RegionPlot3D[region2, AxesLabel->{x, y, z}]`

And to find the area

`P[q_, p_] = {1 + q^2, 1 + p^2, (1 + q^2)/(1 + p^2)}`
`T[q_, p_] = Cross[D[P[q, p], q], D[P[q, p], p]]`
`L = Norm[T[q, p]]`

Thank you for the help

Comment: ... and what is your question here?

Comment: Well i cant seem to get the graph right and my L is coming out incorrect and i don't know why. i believe the final step is to integrate but it doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: `region2 // DiscretizeRegion // Area`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = (1 + x^2)/(1 + y^2);
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1, {x, y}]]
DiscretizeGraphics[%] // Area
NIntegrate[
 Cross[D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, x], D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, y]] // 
  Norm, {x, y} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1, {x, y}]]
```

> `2.69909`

> `2.69588`